# Can I use slotted L brackets to mount glass panels for a shower door?

Tags: doors, shower

I'm looking to do a glass shower door installation and want to know the feasibility.

I have three 1/4" glass panels measuring 30" x 30" each. I would like to stack each panel on top of the other, providing me with a total height of 90". Is this feasible using a slotted L joint/ bracket to hold and secure this configuration? Any recommendations are certainly welcomed!!!!!

Comment: What sort of glass? Ordinary glazing glass (as for a single glazed window) is bad news when it gets knocked and breaks - in a shower. particularly in a movable door.

Comment: Without any more details, this screams "bad idea" due to it likely being the wrong kind of glass to be safely used as a shower door. Also, no clue what a "slotted L joint/bracket" is - a picture or drawing of the thing would be needed at a minimum to understand that.

Comment: A friend of mine was in the shower on July 13, 1977 at about 9:30 PM when the NYC blackout hit. He became disoriented in the dark and put both hands through the plain glass shower door, which sliced into his forearms. Although he didn't bleed to death, he was left with 5 useless claws on one hand. On the other hand, he had 4 useless fingers but he retained an opposable thumb. Just one week prior, Congress had passed a federal law (CPSC 16 CFR 1201) mandating safety glass or tempered glass in shower doors. Too late for poor Kevin.

Comment: This question is too broad and is largely a matter of opinion. Please revise to ask something more specific, and provide enough detail for us to answer.

Comment: Duh - this isn't Law.SE, but details matter. Congress doesn't create CFRs, but it created the Consumer Product Safety Commission in 1972 under the Consumer Product Safety Act. The 1977 regulation 16 CFR 1201 on shower glass was created by the CPSC itself, not by Congress.

Answer (score 2):

Feasibility? Yes, of course it can be achieved. Safety? Forget it. Amount of work involved? Forget it. Practicality? Forget it. Alternatives? Too many to mention!

Comment: I had 200 stitches in my arms for an accident with a glass door when I was 6 yrs old. You should buy something off-the-shelf designed with safety in mind.